# Create symlinks recursively for a whole tree

Tags: linux, find, xargs, tree

I am seeking for a command that would re-create a whole tree of files in a different directory. I would prefer to have all symlinks absolute. Can I do that with a find and xargs? ;-)

Comment: I don't get the idea. If you make, for example, a symlink named `/tmp/somedirectory` pointing at `/home/me/somegreatdir`, then all the contents of `somegreatdir` will be visible under `/tmp/somedirectory`. This needs just **one** symlink for the entire tree. Or what else do you want?

Comment: e.g. first synching the whole structure, but then remove some of them. There are applications for it.

Comment: @jankes, as another example, think of a read-only filesystem you want to use as a cache, but where you might want to add additional files (to your local copy, since you can't modify the original).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`cp -rs source/ dest/` should do the trick. The directory structure will be recreated at dest/ with each file being a symlink to its counterpart in source.

Comment: Also my first attempt. Failed to get `cp` to create symlink for `source/some_deeper_dir/files`.

Comment: In my experience, you have to use the full path to source (e.g. `cp -Rs /home/myusername/source dest`) otherwise it will complain. here's a ref: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-utils/2004-08/msg00039.html

Answer (score 9):

In case `cp -rs` is not the answer you're looking for, `lndir` might be the correct answer.

Comment: Handled perfectly deep subdirectories structures. Installed it on debian using `sudo apt-get install xutils-dev`

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: The `lndir` can handle relative links correctly whereas at least older versions of `cp -rs` only supported absolute paths for the first argument. The `lndir` is officially meant for building X Server from source code so it's actually meant to be used for one specific purpose because (1) `cp -rs` was not supported on all platforms and (2) `cp -rs` didn't support relative path as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do in this way:

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

This will symlink all files in `sites-available` folder to `sites-enabled`