# Utility for creating symlink to directory tree

Tags: linux, shell, symbolic-link

I remember that there is an utility for GNU/Linux, that given some directory,
builds the same directory hierarchy, but with all regular files replaced by symlinks
to the corresponding ones.

I can't remember its name.

Yes, I know it's a simple lesson in shell programming, but no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create symlinks recursively for a whole tree](http://superuser.com/questions/356804/create-symlinks-recursively-for-a-whole-tree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cp** has a **-s** flag, which makes symlinks, instead of copying. You can probably combine it with **-r**, so it recursively links everything, eg.:

```
cp -rs ./folder ./target/
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some [command-line](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1776/create-a-symbolic-link-tree-that-shadows-a-directory-structure) fu?  There are a number of ideas on that page.